Pardot Form Handler: 400 Bad Request Error
I have a Pardot Form Handler which I am submitting a POST request to on the client side.
However, I'm getting the following error along with a 400 Bad Request Error: "This is a form handler page with no content. Use the form's direct URL instead." (This is the same error you get when you just paste the url in the browser.)
I've looked up other answers and my enctype is correct (empty, tried setting it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded as well- making no difference).
I have tried this both on my local environment and a hosted QA environment, from a client with http and https, changing the success and error locations between referring url and specific url, and toggling a bunch of other configs. I also tried adding this as outlined in one of the docs:     <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer-when-downgrade" />
I don't understand enough about the undocumented mechanics behind form handlers to know where to go from here. It seems like it might be stuck on the redirection piece, but also there have been no prospects added to Pardot on the requests where I've gotten this error. It also confuses me that the error is returning me to the actual pardot form handler url to show me the message since it's a POST request, not a GET.
For what it's worth, my ideal solution also has the original site making the request being "cookied" after the pardot form handler redirects back to it.
I am using Vue and need some additional functionality around form submission, so rather than a fully vanilla HTML submission of the form there is some JS - here are the key snippets:
<form
      action="http://www.pardot-form-handler-url.com"
      method="post"
      @submit.prevent="handleSubmitUserVerification"
      ref="userVerificationForm"
    >
      <label for="email">Email <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
      <InputText id="email" v-model="email"></InputText>
      <div v-for="error of v$.email.$errors" :key="error.$uid">
        <div style="color: red">{{ error.$message }}</div>
      </div>
      <Button label="Submit" type="submit" />
    </form>

// rest of HTML
// key method: 

async handleSubmitUserVerification() {
      // validation
      const isFormCorrect = await this.v$.$validate();
      if (!isFormCorrect) {
        console.error("User verification failed.");
        return;
      }

      // more custom logic once form submission working

      // After your custom actions, manually submit the form
      if (true) {
        this.$refs.userVerificationForm.submit();
      }
    },

